# Integral thoughout ellipsoid

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I need help knowing if I am doing the correct approach

, Solve

$$\iiint_{D} |xyz|dxdydz$$ taken throughout the ellipsoid $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$

What I tried;

Let $x/a=u$ $y/b=v$ and $z/c=w$

then I calculated jacobian to be $abc.$

Then I thought; will I need to just evaluate

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}abc|abcuvw|  dudvdw$$

Is this the right way or am I making mistake?

Comment: Check your integration limits.

Comment: @Pavel Hm, what else could it be then? Sorry I cant find my mistake

Comment: hint: $u=v=w=1$ does not satisfy your equation of ellipsoid, but it is in your integration limits...

Comment: @Pavel How about 1/sqrt(3) because I have u^2+v^2+w^2=1

Comment: Still incorrect, since your volume of integration is not a cube, but rather a piece of the ellipsoid. See the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Lets denote the resultant expression as

$F = \iiint_D|xyz|dxdydz$,

where $D$ is the part of space such that $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2} \leq 1$. Then due to the symmetry of the ellipsoid shape

$F = 8\iiint_{D_1}xyzdxdydz$,

where $D_1$ is the part of space such that $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2} \leq 1$ and $x\geq 0$, $y\geq 0$, $z\geq 0$ ($\frac{1}{8}$ of the ellipsoid in the first octant). Then we have

$F = 8\int_0^adx\int_0^{b\sqrt{1-x^2/a^2}}dy\int_0^{c\sqrt{1-x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2}}dzxyz = \frac{1}{6}(abc)^2$.

Hope this helps.